# Error using ajax with cordova for iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ajax, cordova

I developed an app with cordova for iOS and Android, the app allows you to connect the device to a machine using wifi; after the connection with ajax call, I get the status of the machine.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

this is what I have in the config.xml

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://192.168.4.1:80/D?\r',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState +
            " - responseText: " + xhr.responseText +
            " - status: " + xhr.status +
            " - text status: " + textStatus +
            " - error: " + err);
    }
});
```

Using the app with android I have no error and is perfect, iOS does not make the call and I have no response; the error is: readyState is 4 and 502 error.

What I can do? Why iOS block the call?

Thanks

Comment: the iOS device is connected to the same network 192.168.4.x?

Comment: @MartinCisnerosCapistrán Yes, is connected to the unit Wifi

Comment: Ok, what is the purpose for is "\r" in the url? Maybe yo should remove it and test